# VMWare - why can my Virtual Machine access the internet even though it's connected to its own VMNet?

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I have two virtual machines, one windows XP and another Ubuntu both connected to the virtual network VMnet2. I want them only to be able to communicate with one another and not any external network

[image]

For my Windows xp machine I want all internet services to go to the Ubuntu machine so I changed the TCP/IP settings on the XP machine to redirect to the Ubuntu machine:

(where .129 is the xp machine, .128 is the ubuntu)

[image]

But even after doing this I am still able to ping servers that are not the ubuntu machine (e.g google.com) on my xp machine. Why is this happening and how can I make the network air-gapped so only both machines are connected to eachother?

Comment: It sounds like you didn't remove the uplink adapter when defining the virtual switch. http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2043160 When VMWare asks if you want to create a new switch or connect to the existing, leave the Create option radiobutton checked, and uncheck the vmnic under it. that will create a switch with no physical adapters.

Comment: for vSphere client, I select the host, and the configurations tab. under Networking, click Add Networking -> Virtual Machine -> "Create a vSphere standard switch", and uncheck the vmnic selected under that option. then click next to name the network and complete install. Note that in the network illustrations, under Physical Adapters, it should now display "none". Finally, attach the VMs to the new network.